# Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, keycloak, keycloak-services

I got the following Error when keycloak is start and trying to login from admin console..
It takes  to much time it trying to hit server directly and gives error when trying to hit from load balancer..

Can any one tell me how to remove this error.

```
12:46:31,369 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (Timer-2) Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
12:46:31,370 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ScheduledTaskRunner] (Timer-2) Failed to run scheduled task ClearExpiredEvents: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1933)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:558)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentMap.size(PersistentMap.java:140)
    at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:500)
    at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:784)
    at org.keycloak.models.jpa.ClientAdapter.getProtocolMappers(ClientAdapter.java:304)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.entities.CachedClient.<init>(CachedClient.java:75)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.entities.CachedRealm.<init>(CachedRealm.java:201)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.DefaultCacheRealmProvider.getRealm(DefaultCacheRealmProvider.java:153)
    at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.DefaultCacheRealmProvider.getRealms(DefaultCacheRealmProvider.java:193)
    at org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ClearExpiredEvents.run(ClearExpiredEvents.java:16)
    at org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ScheduledTaskRunner.run(ScheduledTaskRunner.java:27)
    at org.keycloak.timer.basic.BasicTimerProvider$1.run(BasicTimerProvider.java:29)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3589)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4019)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(CachedPreparedStatement.java:111)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3039)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3489)
    ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after spending quite a good amount of time I found that the connection url for Data base is wrong.After putting right Connection url it working fine.